# CoreBluetooth crash on reconnect

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on an Swift app that maintains a bluetooth connection with a peripheral, and automatically reconnects when going out of range and then returning.  Before using the periheral, it needs to discover 2 characteristics (RX and TX). 
All works well most of the time, but when trying to reconnect when the signal strength is very low, it sometimes times out before discovering the characteristics. 
I end up with the following crash, but I can't figure out why it's happening or how to fix it.
I am still new to ios development so please be gentle.

Here is my crash log from crashlytics:

```
> # Date: 2016-07-02T05:24:21Z
>
>Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>
>0.  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181699bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
>1.  CoreBluetooth                  0x187904ee0 __29-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:]_block_invoke + 60
>2.  libdispatch.dylib              0x181a6d630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
>3.  libdispatch.dylib              0x181a6d5f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
>4.  libdispatch.dylib              0x181a72cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
>5.  CoreFoundation                 0x181fd0bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
>6.  CoreFoundation                 0x181fcea18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
>7.  CoreFoundation                 0x181efd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
>8.  GraphicsServices               0x18340c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
>9.  UIKit                          0x186d74d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
>10. Grainfather_Connect            0x10010d518 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
>11. libdispatch.dylib              0x181a9e8b8 (Missing)
>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the exception message?  What line of code did it crash on?  It looks like it is a callback block and my guess is that something is null, but without more information we can't say.

Comment: Looks like an unfortunate internal error. I don't see your application anywhere on the stack trace you posted. File a bug I guess, unless you can reproduce the bug while attached to the debugger and maybe get more info.